# Rails Engine - File to import not found or unreadable: font-awesome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome, rails-engines

I did a super simple rails app and used font-awesome with no problem. Expanding this to do the same steps in a rails engine produces the following error.

```
File to import not found or unreadable: font-awesome
```

I am unable to find a solution.  If anyone has suggestions on how to make this simple rails engine work with font-awesome, I would be most appreciative.

#### Steps to generate the rails engine and setup font-awesome...

**create the basic engine with one model class for testing**

```
rails plugin new testeng --full --mountable 
cd testeng
bundle install
rails g scaffold book title:string desc:string
rake db:migrate
```

**add in font-awesome**

edit testeng.gemspec and add sass-rails and font-awesome gems after the rails gem is included

```
  s.add_dependency 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
  s.add_dependency 'font-awesome-rails'
```

rename application.css to application.css.scss

```
cd app/assets/stylesheets/testeng/
mv application.css application.css.scss
```

edit app/assets/stylesheets/testeng/application.css.scss and append import statement at end of file.

```
@import 'font-awesome';
```

edit app/views/testeng/books/index.html.erb and use some font-awesome icons

```
<h1>Listing books</h1>

<%= link_to content_tag(:i, '', :class => "fa fa-plus-circle"), new_book_path  %>
```

**start rails server**

```
cd <root-app-path>
bundle install
cd test/dummy
bundle install
rails s
```

**Test in browser**

http://localhost:3000/testeng/books

**Get ERROR**

```
File to import not found or unreadable: font-awesome
```

Comment: Try `@import 'font-awesome.css';`. If that fails, maybe you might want to resort to using `font-awesome-sass` (https://github.com/FortAwesome/font-awesome-sass).

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue , with the below message :

```
Sass::SyntaxError at /
File to import not found or unreadable: font-awesome-sprockets.
Load paths:
  /home/user/shop_app/depot2/app/assets/images
  /home/user/shop_app/depot2/app/assets/javascripts
```

And fixed it by updating the gem to include the version :

changed from:

```
 gem 'font-awesome-sass'
```

to:

```
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.4.0'
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. However, I was getting an error and had to use version 4.6.1. 

https://github.com/FortAwesome/font-awesome-sass/issues/114

Answer (score 3):

Install font-awesome-sass instead:

```
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.4.0'
```

Bundle it:

```
bundle install
```

Add the following to your application.css.scss (app/assets/stylesheets):

```
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
```

As a test you can add the following line to your view to see if it works:

```
<%= icon('thumbs-up', 'It Worked!!!', id: 'my-icon', class: 'fa-5x') %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I restarted the server and everything worked fine.
Try restarting server