# @import 'font-awesome' doesn't work in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, import, sass, font-awesome

I'm trying to:

```
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
```

at the end of my application.css.scss file.

First with instructions provided by fontawesome website, then as in [this stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28356062/rails-engine-file-to-import-not-found-or-unreadable-font-awesome)

then as in this [github topic](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/363)

None of the solutions worked for me.

My gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.4'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.4.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end
group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end
```

My application.html.erb head section:

```
<head>
  <title>Grzegorz Milanowski - Personal Website</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
          <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/application.css">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

Error:

```
Sass::SyntaxError in Welcome#index
Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #8 raised:

File to import not found or unreadable: font-awesome-sprockets.
Load paths:
  /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/assets/images
  /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/assets/javascripts
  /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/assets/stylesheets
  /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/jquery-rails-4.1.1/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.1.1/lib/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/turbolinks-source-5.0.0/lib/assets/javascripts
Extracted source (around line #329):
327
328
329
330

}

@import 'font-awesome-sprockets';
@import 'font-awesome';
```

I will appreciate any help. Let me know if some more logs are needed.

Comment: I just added and it is working. Can you restart your server and try again? Also make sure your gem is installed.

Comment: Ok got it. Remove this line `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/application.css">` You don't need it.

Comment: I deleted the link to application.css and restarted server at once. I suppose that restarting the server helped. Its silly beceause I spent about two hours for this. Thanks for your time @Arup

Comment: No issues. I knew exactly what the issue was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems after adding `gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.4.0'` to `Gemfile` you forgot to `bundle install`, do `bundle install` it will fix your issue

**Note:** no need of `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/application.css">` you can remove it.